# CompletableFuture.get() equivalent in javascript Promise?

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, promise, completable-future

I recently programming in Typescript/Javascript from JAVA 8. As soon as I encountered `async/await`, it reminded me of `CompletableFuture`. In java, regardless of the return type of a method, I can call `someMethodReturningFuture.get()` inside a method and can block the execution at will. But in JavaScript why do we need to declare a method as `async` when we want to block on some other asynchronous method using `await`? May be there is something so wrong that I am believing till now about `Java/CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 0):

Because JS has a *synchronous execution model*. The resulting behaviour is often described as "single threaded". For sure you could block that "single thread" to wait for the resolution of a promise, but that would block *anything²*, a behaviour that you probably don't want, and thus it is not part of the language.

<sub>²: including browser rendering / reacting to the user, as well as the promise resolution itself ...</sub>